# Preventing rotation of symbols in ArcGIS Map service export request?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dynamic-layer

I have a system (ArcGIS Server 10.5, ArcGIS JavaScript 4.3) whereby I'm allowing the user to rotate the map, and then request a PDF output of the map.

I need to ensure that the symbology is always oriented upwards - i.e. not rotated with the dataframe.

I've updated the following registry key, and this helps ensure that when viewed in the MXD, and created as PDF output, the icons are oriented correctly, i.e. towards top of page/screen.

```
HKEY_USERS\[USERID]\Software\ESRI\Server10.5\Symbology\Settings\RotateWithTransform
```

However, in my web client, when my app does a MapServer export with rotation, the symbology is always oriented North - e.g.:

[image]

Is this normal behaviour? Labels are oriented correctly - see further example, again rotated 15 degrees:

[image]

Is there something I can do to ensure that the icons are not rotated?

Note - this is also asked at https://geonet.esri.com/message/687825-prevent-rotation-of-symbols-in-map-service-export-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I confirmed with Esri that this functionality is not supported.

Comment: If it is important to you, did you seek/submit and ArcGIS Idea to have it supported?